# checkbox не передеает значение в форме

Tags: html, вёрстка

Если `chekbox`не выбран, то при `submit` формы не передается значение `false`.  Как сделать чтобы он передавался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox" value="false" />

bool checked = Request.Form["checkbox"] != "false";
```

Comment: Тогда в форме будет передано два значения, что далеко не всегда приемлемо (я рад за ваш `Request.Form`, который выкинул одно из значений, но такое не везде)

Comment: Ну, тогда не «выкинул», а «объединил». Не знаю даже, что хуже :)

Comment: спасибо за ответ )

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую никак. Если чекбокс не выбран, он вообще не передаётся на сервер. В отличие, например, от пустого текстового поля. Это легко проверить с помощью isset, отправив пустой type="text" и пустой type="checkbox":

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="text" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="отправить" />
</form>

<?
if(isset($_POST['text'])) {
    echo "text_true"; //выведет "text_true": значения нету, но элемент в массиве $_POST есть
}
else {
    echo "text_false";
}
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    echo "check_true";
}
else {
    echo "check_false"; //выведет "check_false", т.е. в принципе нету такого элемента в массиве $_POST
}
?>
```

Если очень надо передавать на сервер true/false состояния чекбокса, можно делать проверку на клиенте и заносить результат в поле hidden, а уже значение hidden получать на сервере:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="text" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="отправить" />
</form>

$('form').submit(function(){
    if(!$('[name="checkbox"]').prop('checked')) {
        $('[name="hidden"]').val(false);
    }
    else {
        $('[name="hidden"]').val(true);
    }
});

<? echo $_POST['hidden']; ?>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ )

Answer (score 0):

Можно так (почти как **user176262**, но наоборот, и поэтому короче):

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox" value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="true" />
```

То есть скрытое поле нужно размещать ДО чекбокса.